# Is it a good idea to keep large resistors in feedback path of a comparator circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog, comparator

I was seeing a comparator circuit designed with [LM2903](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393b.pdf?ts=1692084019708&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). The circuit diagram is given below. It is working as expected in simulation.

In the feedback path you can see a 1 MΩ resistor.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to put large resistors in feedback path?
2. Will this increase the noise pick up, because a large resistor in feedback path creates a high impedance node.

[image]

Comment: Google "comparator with hysteresis".

Comment: Yes, this configuration is pretty usual. There is no high impedance node, the input impedance is mainly given by R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were a linear amplifier, then 1MΩ as the negative feedback impedance could indeed be problematic, since even tiny noise currents in that path can result in the op-amp producing significant output potential changes in response.

But this isn't a linear amplifier, this is a comparator, and the feedback is not negative, it's positive.

The comparator is intended to produce an output either hard up against the positive supply (a job done by R4) or hard against the negative supply (0V in this case), achieved by U1's output transistor. It's as far from "linear" as its possible to be, and you should *not* expect any noise in R4 to produce any linearly amplified version of that noise at the output.

Also, since the feedback provided by R3 is positive, and intended to produce [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis), R3 actually *improves* noise immunity. When the output changes state, this positive feedback causes a change at the input which *reinforces* the very condition that initiated the change in the first place, which pushes the output even harder towards some extreme.

Contrast this with negative feedback, in which a change at the amplifier's output alters the input in *opposition* to the initial cause of that change, leading to linearity. Negative feedback aims to precisely control gain, increase stability, and provide a linear analogue output. Positive feedback (in this particular application) aims to dispense with linearity altogether, to produce a strictly digital high or low output, and to introduce input hysteresis.

Answer (score 3):

> *Will this increase the noise pick up, because a large resistor in
> feedback path creates a high impedance node.*

Hint: the impedance at the non-inverting input is dominated by R2 (52.3 kΩ) and not the 1 MΩ resistor (R3) nor the input resistor R1: -

[image]